# Using a custom Application with InstrumentationTestCase

Tags: android, testing

I have an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 (which is a subclass of InstrumentationTestCase).  When running my testcases, I need to launch my activities using a custom TestApplication object, since this TestApplication objects has some configuration necessary for my tests.

However, I don't see a way to customize my ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 testcases to use the test Application object.  Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better way, but I was able to accomplish this by using a custom TestRunner.

```
public class MyInstrumentationTestRunner extends InstrumentationTestRunner {

    @Override
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return new MyTestApplication(context);       
    }


}
```

I also needed to modify my test project's AndroidManifest.xml to specify the new runner:

```
<instrumentation android:name="com.mypackage.test.MyInstrumentationTestRunner" ... />
```

And I had to modify my IDE to use the specified test runner as well.  If you're running from the command line, you'll need to do something like the following instead:

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.mypackage/com.mypackage.test.MyInstrumentationTestRunner
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
@Override
public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return Instrumentation.newApplication(YourAppClass.class, context);      
}
```

Because it injects Context to a wrapper correctly