# Controlling Application during testing android

Tags: android, testing

I using Roboguice to test application. I have two `Modules` for the app:

- ProductionModule - used when application is not under test
- TestingModule - used when application is under test

Those Modules are parameters for Injector which created in `OnCreate()` method of **APPLICATION**.

So how can i figure out, if the app is under test?
Is there a way to manage an **APPLICATION** lifecycle in `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, so i can do some stuff **BEFORE APPLICATION** `onCreate()` method?

PS: I need to test activities after that so i using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and i using custom `TestRunner` to generate reports.

Comment: There is a way like used in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159387/using-a-custom-application-with-instrumentationtestcase), but is there any documentation how test-runner works? i think, that writing custom test-runner is the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application on create is called before any of your tests run, this is because to run tests your application already has to exist.

You can however call application oncreate yourself within a test. You can cast an applicationcontext to your application and then call the onCreate method. I have had to do this in the past in order to clear any state in the application.

Comment: I tried that, but sometimes when i call `onCreate()` by myself, `onCreate()` method invoked by system yet not finished, and this cause   system to be blocked. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You can send extra params to the activity from JUnit in the setUp() like this:

```
@Override
public void setUp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("debug", true);
    setActivityIntent(intent);
    mActivity = getActivity();
}
```

And inside the real Activity you can check it like this inside onCreate():

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            boolean is= (Boolean)extras.get("debug");
            if(is){
                // here you are in debug mode
            }
        }
```

Comment: It wont work in my case, because activities uses singleton classes, that initiated in Application class. So i can't change instance of singleton via Intent